# How to load URL via JavaScript asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

I have this URL which needs to be loaded after the page has been loaded. I am trying to load the URL via Javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.adtol.com/native/1/1/0/1"></script>
```

But, whenever I add async to this script doesn't load.

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="//www.adtol.com/native/1/1/0/1"></script>
```

The src doesn't actually load the js file, it fetches data from server.

What can I do to load the URL asynchrounously via Javascript?

You can visit the `src` URL for better idea.

Comment: Do you get an error on one of your own js files when you add `async`? If that's the case, that's what async itself means i-e. it won't wait to load before your custom script is loaded.

Comment: *"But, whenever I add async to this script doesn't load"* `async` is supported by all major browsers (even IE11 -- actually, I think Microsoft created `async`). What do you mean by "doesn't load"? You get an error? You see nothing in the Network panel? I find it extremely unlikely that it just doesn't load.

Comment: See also: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-async

Comment: The `src` is not actually a .js file, it is URL

Comment: @EvilTech - All `src`s are URLs. But your `//www.adtol.com/native/1/1/0/1` returns JavaScript code, right? That's what your `script` tag says it does.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't load?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The URL actually runs on server side and has a php script and the ouput is written via `document.write`.